# Solving mod problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Can somebody run me through a step-by-step of how to solve a problem of this nature?

$3x+5\equiv 12 \mod 5$

Comment: The algebra is all the same; all that really changes is that $2=7$ and other similar things, and that you can't use long division to compute a quotient. (and occasionally, there are some more complex issues regarding division, but they don't arise here)

Comment: So 3x ≡ 7 (mod 5)?

Comment: That is indeed true. Though the problem as stated was trying to help you a bit: note that $3x = 12$ is the same equation as $3x = 7$. I think it was hoping you'd substitute $5 \to 0$ before continuing on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
3x + 5 \equiv 12 \mod 5 \\
3x \equiv 7 \equiv 2  \mod 5
$$
Now via Euclide algorithm: $3\times 2 - 5 = 1$ so $$3\times 2 \equiv 1  \mod 5\\
3\times 4 \equiv 2 = 3x  \mod 5\\
0 \equiv 3(x-4)  \mod 5$$ and multiply by 2:
$$
0 \equiv 2\times 3(x-4)  \equiv x - 4  \mod 5\\
x \equiv 4  \mod 5
$$

Comment: My mind has the hardest time wrapping around mod.. I'll need a further breakdown if you would be so kind.

Comment: Tell me what remains a problem.

Comment: the arithmetic basics that are available when working with mod. i'm just not seeing how this works, even after multiple tutorials and plenty of reading

Comment: You have to remember the trick to divise by $a \mod b$: look for a solution to the Bezout equation $au + bv = 1$. Use that 1. to find a solution (find $x = 4$) and 2. prove unicity (last two lines, get rid of the $3\times$).

Comment: If perhaps you could refer to a very basic, a,b,c link as to how this works, that would be great. You answered the question so I suppose that is as much as I can ask.

Comment: You were given $3x\equiv12\pmod 5$, since $(4,5)=1$ you could have just divided through by $3$...

Comment: You have an equation $ax = c$. All I did was to find a solution $x_0$: $ax_0 = c$ and prove this was the only one, ie $a(x-x_0) = 0\Rightarrow x=x_0$. This is done via the Euclide algorithm in the strange world of mod arithmetic.

Comment: @chubakueno: did you mean $(3,5) = 1$? if so, this simplification is a consequence of Bezout theorem.

Comment: yeah i'm really missing the primary basics of this type of problem.. they are strange...

Comment: Yes, I meant that, sorry. You can prove this without Bezout by setting $3x=12+5k$, which implies that $k=3q$for some $q$ and dividing by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the hard part is finding inverses, i.e. how to divide.
Therefore, one possibility (apart from guessing, which in cases with small numbers like these is possibly the fastest) is using the euclidean algorithm: In this case find integers $a,b$ such that
$$3a+5b=1.$$
Then $a$ is an inverse of 3 mod 5.
Also works for non prime numbers as long as they are coprime (gcd=1).

A step by step solution for a problem of the kind
$$rx+s=t\text{ mod }u$$
with gcd(u,r)=1
would then be:

Step 1: Simplify everything by substracting $s$ and "modding out" as much $u$ as possible

Step 2: Use euclidean algorithm to find modular inverse of r

Step 3: Multiply everything by this inverse

Step 4: Read off result (maybe simplify again).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When considering modular arithmetic, look at it like a clock. For example our clock is mod 12. You have the digits 1 - 12, however after that it starts over again at one. Think of mod 5 as a clock that only goes to 5. 
I find it easiest to calculate the equation using base 10 (the way we learned to do math in elementary school) and then divide that number by  the mod that I am in (in this case mod 5 ). Then, your remainder is the number you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$\!{\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}m\!:\ an\equiv  ax\!+\!\overbrace{\color{#c00}my}^{\equiv\ 0}\equiv ax\!\iff\! a(x\!-\!n)\equiv 0\!\iff\!m\mid a(x\!-\!n)\!\overset{\ \color{#0a0}{(m,a)\,=\,1}}\iff\! m\mid x\!-\!n\, $ by $\rm\color{#0a0}{Euclid.}$

$\!{\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}5\!:\ 3\cdot 4\equiv  3x + \color{#c00}5\,\equiv\, 3x\!\iff\ldots$